# Origin and correct meaning of "make political book"

Tags: meaning, etymology, politics

Re-watching old episodes of the X-Files. In which Agent Mulder says: (paraphrasing)

> just pseudo-science used *to make political book*

([Transcript here](http://www.generationterrorists.com/cgi-bin/x-files.cgi?ep=3x23))

*(FYI The Episode was written by Mat Beck)*

I can infer that it means, to add (false) weight to a political agenda or argument. (ie. making it a safer bet.)

I recall hearing the phrase before, sounds like a Hunter S Thompson, or beat era style phrase, but I'm unable to find any reference to it.

Can anyone help with **definite** meaning and/or etymology?

*Edit: Please don't offer conjecture, I can guess all by myself.*

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "make _a_ political book" or "make political _books_"?

Comment: @J.R. It's definitely "make political book"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Book making](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/book?q=book+making#book__43) means taking bets. The term [bookmaker](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=book+making&searchmode=none) in this sense, according to etymonline, is first found in 1862 and originates from the literal sense of making a book.

If you are a book maker then you set the odds on the things being gambled on. What Mulder means is that the pseudo-science is being used to fix the odds of certain things happening in politics.

Comment: I believe what you mean to say is "What I think Mulder means is..."

Comment: Nope, that's not what I mean to say.

Comment: Plausible enough.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I love the X-Files, I'm afraid Mulder is misusing the phrase here.

To "make book" is a back-formation from "[bookmaker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bookmaker?s=t)"; it means "to take bets".

I believe Mulder is mixing it up with "to score (political) points"; there's an easy association of ideas (one might keep score in a book; in fact, a bookmaker might keep score!)  "To make political book" is not, however, a usually-accepted phrase.

Comment: I know the phrase to "make book", it doesn't quite feel the same as the way it's phrased in the X-Files. Perhaps Mat Beck is creatively mixing his metaphors.